# Create a custom spaced repetition schedule

Tags: calendar, reminders

I think many of you know what [spaced repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) learning technique is, how it is done. It does not follow any rigid pattern. Rather there are different theories to it. But as far as repetition is concerned it is irregular. My goal is to schedule an automated reminder from the day I've learnt something, to 4th day, 10th day, 30th day etc. It may very upon individual user.

So, I'd like to know how can I create a task or event to remind me in 4 days, 10 days, 30 days and 60 days?

My preferred OS is Android, Windows or web-based. It can be in any price.

Comment: "any price" doesn't make sense. within $80k ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Knowledge Tool Kit android app from google play

1. Create topic, subtopic and contents.
2. Create alerts to remind you on a specific date and time or schedule to remind daily/weekly/monthly.

[Knowledge Tool Kit - Android app Demo - Automate hourly daily weekly message and quiz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO7rHlZfKk8)

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page you link has a whole section for [spaced repetition software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition#Software). There is even a [list of flashcard software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flashcard_software). You can choose any of them that fits you most. Among them, probably Anki is the most popular.

One concern is that the programs may not be able to remind you if you don't run it. So you may want to set the program to automatically start daily.